# Get "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user" when using WP Rest API and Application Password

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to create a post using rest API and Application Password authentification.

So I create credentials using the "Add New Application Password"

[image]

and then I run :

```
curl --user "veptuneapp:APPLICATION_PASSWORD" -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-i https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts \
-d '{"title": "foo bar", "content": "test"}'
```

But I got :

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Normally, with the lasts version of WP, I don't need to install any plugin.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should present your *username* in place of your app password name in `--user`.

Comment: It works, thanks.